# How does \newcommand work? Making easier color command

Tags: macros, color, definition

I'm trying to write an easier color command `\c{}` that is shorter and easier to use than `\color{}`. However, I do not want to overwrite an existing command, so I will use `\providecommand{}[]{}` to create the command.

My question is: How does command options and arguments work?

The command needs to have 1 mandatory argument, the color. Also, like the `\color{}` command, the argument needs to be a defined color.

I'm thinking something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{netflixred}{HTML}{E50914}
\definecolor{overleafgreen}{HTML}{138A07}

\providecommand{\c}[1]{\color{#1}}

\begin{document}
    {\c{netflixred}This text is in netflixred}, 
    {\c{overleafgreen} and this is in overleafgreen}
\end{document}
```

But how do I create the argument for the command? And how do I, in general, create optional and mandatory arguments for commands?

Comment: Yes, thats why I said I would use `\providecommand` to NOT overwrite an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional TeX way to define a new command is with `\def`; this works in LaTeX, as well.  Arguments are given numbers with `#`; e.g., `#1#2`:

```
\def\hello#1#2{Hello, #1!  I'm #2!}
```

However, `\def` will *not* warn you when you're overwriting existing commands.  `\newcommand` is the LaTeX version, and it offers some additional benefits, including a refusal to overwrite a command that already exists.

```
\newcommand{\hello}[2]{Hello, #1!  I'm #2!}
```

If you want to include an optional argument, include another square-bracket bit; the second point in square brackets indicates that there's an optional argument, and gives its default value if it's not specifically included:

```
\newcommand{\hello}[2][Joe]{Hello, #2!  I'm #1!}
```

The optional argument will be `#1`, and subsequent arguments will be mandatory.  So if you say `\hello{Mike}`, you'll get `Hello, Mike!  I'm Joe!`; but if you run `\hello[Jim]{Mike}`, you'll get `Hello, Mike!  I'm Jim!`.

So, for your color command, I would suggest the following:

```
\newcommand{\co}[1]{\color{#1}}
```

That said, I'm not sure how much easier you could want than `\color{blue}`.  Is there some particular reason that this is too long or cumbersome for you?  Five keystrokes is a pretty tiny overhead.

Also, do *not* redefine `\c`.  That's an accent command, for the cedille, and it should really be left alone.

Comment: Thanks. Does it work with several optional arguments?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not; it only allows one optional argument.  Multiple optional arguments requires some dark TeX magic that's almost assuredly overkill for your problem.

Comment: `\newcommand{\co}[1]{\color{#1}}` could more easily be written `\newcommand{\co}{\color}` although I would use `\textcolor` here rather than `\color`.

Comment: Good point.  `\textcolor` is what to use if you've got a short piece you want colored.